# Is the following sentence correct and easy to read?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is this sentence correct and easy to read?

> Whether speculating on commodities is a lucrative business venture or
> not is something that should be considered.

Does it need punctuation?

> Whether speculating on commodities is a lucrative business venture or
> not, is something that should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

> Whether speculating on commodities is a lucrative business venture or not is something that should be considered.

Generally, I avoid placing commas between subjects and their verbs except when a subject ends with the same word as its verb, like the following example from [this site.](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_a_long_subject.htm)

> Those who know, know.

Different sites give other different exceptions, including length and complexity of the subject.

In our case here, going without the comma works fine.